# The example java custom rules doesn't work when I analyse in SonarQube

Tags: java, sonarqube

I am learning to write custom rules according to the steps on SonarQube website.
https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Writing+Custom+Java+Rules+101
Then I put the rules into the SonarQube. But it doesn't work when I analyse the example code.
I have already seen the rule in SonarQube server.
[SonarQube server shows the rule](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ZLwU.png)
But it doesn't analyse to show the bug.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bcapm.png)
My example code as following:

```
public class Example {
void foo(){

  }
int bar(int i){
    return 0;
  }
}
```

My SonarQube version is 7.0.

Comment: So what exactly is your question? You will have to put more information for people to understand the problem

Comment: did you use these rules to write your rules? [Writing+Custom+Java+Rules+101](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Writing+Custom+Java+Rules+101)

Comment: I have already uploaded the pictures.Actually the problem is the rule can't take effect and I don't know how to find the reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried to activate the rule on your current quality profile? That's the first thing I always forget when developing a new rule. Sometimes they are showing up on the rules list but they're not active for any of our quality profiles.

Comment: Do you mean that I will add this rule to the RulesList.java with these code?`.add(MyFirstCustomCheck.class)`

Comment: Not just that. I mean activate your new rule on your Quality profile on the web console. 
- Go to your http://<yourHost>:9000 (It's very important to be logged in as an admin) 
- Rules 
- On the left side, filter by your repository (Find your repository name on CustomRulesDefinition.java or some class that implements RulesDefinition on your plugin) 
- You should see your new rules then and a button to activate them to your Quality Profiles

Comment: Another thing that I realised is that I can only run my own rules using a child of SonarWay Java Quality Profile. If nothing works for you, try copying the sonar native profile and then using the copy (with your rules activated on this copied profile) that worked for me aswell

Comment: ahhhh.....I see...Thanks a lot!!! I find it under the inactive tags.But the Quality Profile doesn't have a activate button.Do you mean that I should create a Quality Profile to activate all the rules?

Comment: Make sure you are logged in as an admin to activate your new rules to your Quality Profiles (even your newly copied ones). Otherwise they will still be inactive! If you're logged in and have all the permissions, an "Activate" button should appear on that list you saw.

Comment: Well...I log in as an admin...But I doesn't have any premissions in the native Quality Profiles"Sonar way"...So I create the new one to activate my custom rules...Thanks..

Comment: I'm glad it's working! If you could mark it as answered it would be nice!
https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers